# Can't ignore a DataMember in UWP (C#)

Tags: c#, serialization, uwp

I need to serialize a class which contains an `StorageFile` (a class which cant be serialized) as an attribute. Although I tagged that attribute as `[IgnoreDataMember]` the `XmlSerializer` keeps tryng to serialize it, what isn't expected.

An snippet to clarify the issue:

```
[DataContract]
public class Attachment
{
    [DataMember]
    public string FileName { get; set; }

    [IgnoreDataMember]
    public StorageFile File { get; set; }

    [DataMember]
    public Boolean UserCreatedContent { get; set; }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like you mixed the `XmlSerializer` and the `DataContractSerializer` a little bit. The [DataContractAttribute](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.serialization.datacontractattribute(v=vs.110).aspx) is an attribute to control a `DataContractSerializer` but you are using a `XmlSerializer`. This means the attributes are meaningless because the serializers are not the same as you can see in [this article](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/wcf/feature-details/using-the-xmlserializer-class).

To control the serialisation using the `XmlSerializer` you should have look at [the attributes that control XML serialization](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb552742(v=vs.120).aspx). This means you don't need much attributes, simply use `XmlIgnore` a single time to ignore the property during serialisation using the `XmlSerializer`.

```
public class Attachment
{
    public string FileName { get; set; }
    [XmlIgnore]
    public StorageFile File { get; set; }
    public Boolean UserCreatedContent { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the pretty explanatory answer! All answers above fixed the problem but this also answered why.

Answer (score 1):

Try using the `XmlIgnoreAttribute` attribute instead

Answer (score 1):

Use the `XmlIgnore` Attribute if you're using `XmlSerializer`

```
public class Attachment
{
    public string FileName { get; set; }

    [XmlIgnore]
    public StorageFile File { get; set; }

    public Boolean UserCreatedContent { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer! That fixed the problem